# An algorithm to determinate inequality relations

Tags: algorithm

This question is about whether or not the existence of an algorithm. First, I have a set T consisting of things no identified, that is, I don't know if two elements are equal or different. However, I have a function, in some programing language(more specific, in R) able to determinate if two or three things of T are different, but only different. For example, suppose that T = {A, B, C},
so my function works like this:

```
f(B,C) = (0,1)  means that C is not equal to B;

f(B,C) = (0,0)  nothing to say about B and C. In other words, B and C can be equal or different;

f(B,C) = (1,1)  the same thing of the last example, B and C can be equal or different;
```

In addition, this function works with any group of three elements

```
f(A,B,C) = (0,0,1), that means that C is not equal to A and B, but A and B can be equal or different, that is, nothing to say.
```

two more examples,

```
f(A,B,C) = (1,2,3) means that A, B, C are different mutually

f(A,B,C) = (1,0,1)  means that A and C aren't no equals to B, but A and C can be equal or different, that is, nothing to say.
```

In summary, different digits mean inequalities, but the same digit indicate no relation, neither equal or different.

I would like to generate other function f2 using the f function and any algorithm(?) able to evaluate any set T with n elements > 3.

Something like this:

```
f2(T)
if cardinality of T < 3, return f(T)
else 
.......
```

Where f2 behave just like f. That is, for example,

```
f2(A,B,C,D) = (0,1,0,0) meaning that A, B or D is not iqual to C, but nothing to say between A, B and D.
```

one more example

```
 f2(A,B,C,D,E,F) = (1,2,3,4,0,0) meaning that A,B,C and D are mutually not iqual, but E and F with no relation.
```

Is possible some algorithm?

Comment: Clarification question: is f2 supposed to behave just like f, but support more than 3 arguments? Is that what you mean by 'evaluate any set'?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to evaluate somthing like this f2(A,B,C,D) = (1,1,0,0) meaning that A or B is not equal to C or D. I will edit this in the question.

Comment: This sounds like connected components but instead of edges you're looking for cuts in the graph. Might be able to start out with a fully connected graph, cut all edges you find: `(1, 2, 3)` meaning you can cut 3 edges, `(1, 0, 1)` allows 2 cuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your 'inequality' function is exactly equivalent to a proper subset grouping function. In other words:

```
f(a,b) -> (x,y)
```

really means

```
there exists proper subsets x and y of T
such that a is an element of x and b is an element of y
```

To convert to inequalities, we know if elements are in different proper (i.e. non-overlapping) subsets then they must not be equal. If they're in the same subset then they may or may not be equal.

So now creating an equivalent function for more than two elements involves creating a set of subsets to put each element into.

So, roughly, the algorithm is:

```
f(Set s)
    for each element in S
        use f to determine which other elements it is in a subset with
    for each pair of element
        if they are in the same subsets as all other elements
            they are in the same subset in the result
        else
            they are in different subsets
```

Here is some Java code that implements the algorithm with some associated tests. I apologise for the terse use of streams. I can explain how it works if required.

```
public class Inequality {

    private final Set<Set<String>> inequalities = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(String... elements) {
        inequalities.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(elements)));
    }

    public List<Integer> get(String... elements) {
        List<Set<String>> distinctSets = Arrays.stream(elements)
                .map(el -> knownUnequalElements(Arrays.asList(elements), el))
                .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Arrays.stream(elements)
                .map(el -> distinctSets.indexOf(knownUnequalElements(Arrays.asList(elements), el)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Set<String> knownUnequalElements(List<String> list, String element) {
        return inequalities.stream()
                .filter(ineq -> ineq.contains(element))
                .flatMap(ineq -> ineq.stream().filter(other -> !other.equals(element)))
                .filter(list::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Note that I just ignore elements that aren't known to be unequal. I only add the elements that are known to be unequal to the set (of sets).

```
@Test
public void testInequalities() {
    Inequality inequality = new Inequality();
    inequality.add("A", "B");
    inequality.add("A", "D");
    inequality.add("B", "D");
    assertThat("unknown elements", inequality.get("E", "F"), is(Arrays.asList(0, 0)));
    assertThat("unknown inequality", inequality.get("A", "C"), is(Arrays.asList(0, 0)));
    assertThat("known inequality", inequality.get("B", "D"), is(Arrays.asList(0, 1)));
    assertThat("commutativity", inequality.get("D", "B"), is(Arrays.asList(0, 1)));
    assertThat("unknown triple", inequality.get("E", "F", "G"), is(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0)));
    assertThat("known triple", inequality.get("A", "B", "D"), is(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2)));
}
```

Comment: It is confussed yet. For example, suppose that T = (A,B,C,D), with the followings outputs f(A,B)=(0,1),f(A,C)=(0,0),f(A,D)=(0,1), f(B,C)=(0,0), f(B,D)=(0,1) and f(C,D)=(0,0)